# Python create nested lists from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, read.csv

I need to import datas from a csv file into python into a list that looks like that:

```
list1 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
         [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
         [(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]
```

So that I can access elements

```
list1[0] = [(0, 1), (0, 2),(0, 3)]    # type list

list1[0][0] = (0,1)    # type tuple

list1[0][0][0] = 0    #type int
```

I have the integers on a csv file that I can manipulate as I want. No specific format is required
Right now data is in six columns without spacing, or six integers per line

I tried this code but it didn't work as I wanted:

```
import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  list1 = list(reader)

print(list1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV import with nested list creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652131/python-csv-import-with-nested-list-creation)

Comment: please mention your csv file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a bit more work to format the list like you want.

Assuming your csv file has six integers per line, something like this might work:

```py
import csv

list1 = []
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        # split line into pairs of integers
        pairs = [(int(i), int(j)) for i, j 
                 in zip(line[0::2], line[1::2])]
        list1.append(pairs)
```

**Edit:**

@gregorio-pedullà asked for an explanation of the indexing used in the line

```py
pairs = [(int(i), int(j)) for i, j 
         in zip(line[0::2], line[1::2])]
```

When slicing sequences in Python, the syntax is `sequence[start:stop:step]`.  If you omit `stop`, then the slice will automatically stop at the end of the sequence.

So `line[0::2]` means "start at the first item (index 0) and take every other item until the end of the list."  In simple terms, this will extract all the items with even indices.

Similarly, `line[1::2]` means "start at the second item and take every other item until the end of the list."  This will extract all the items with odd indices.

If you want to play around with an example, run this:

```py
example_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

evens = example_list[0::2]
print(evens)
# [0, 2, 4]

odds = example_list[1::2]
print(odds)
# [1, 3, 5]

print(zip(evens, odds))
# [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

In your case, you wanted to extract pairs of integers from each line.  One of the simplest ways to create pairs of consecutive items in a list is to slice the even-indexed items and the odd-indexed items, then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them.

Comment: could you clarify the the index 0::2 and 1::2 used in this part of the code? in zip(line[0::2], line[1::2])

Comment: Sure!  I edited my answer with an explanation.  Let me know if you'd like further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that your structure is 3-dimensional, but csv files are best for 2-dimensional data. There's a secondary challenge that your innermost level is made up of tuples, but the outer levels are lists.

You can resolve both of these challenges by treating this as a simple list of lists of generic python objects (i.e., ignoring the fact that the tuples define a 3rd dimension). Then you can use code like this:

```
import csv, ast
# store some sample data
list1 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
         [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
         [(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]

with open('file1.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(list1)

# read the sample data
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    list2 = [
        [ast.literal_eval(t) for t in row]
        for row in r
    ]

list2 == list1
# True
```

Note that the innermost objects will get stored as the string representation of a tuple. Then when they are read back, `ast.literal_eval` converts them back into tuples.

Alternatively, I would highly recommend normalizing the data representation, e.g., storing one (x, y) pair in each row of the csv file, along with their row and column coordinates. That can be done like this:

```
import csv

# store some sample data
list1 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
         [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
         [(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]

with open('file1.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(list1):
        for j, (x, y) in enumerate(row):
            w.writerow([i, j, x, y])

# read the sample data
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    raw_data = [[int(v) for v in row] for row in r]

# figure out how many rows and columns there are
height = max(i for i, j, x, y in raw_data) + 1
width = max(j for i, j, x, y in raw_data) + 1
# create an empty "array" of the right size
list2 = [[None] * width for r in range(height)]
# fill up the array
for i, j, x, y in raw_data:
    list2[i][j] = (x, y)

list2 == list1
# True
```

As another alternative: it sounds like you have a free choice of file structure, since you are not required to organize your csv any particular way. In that case, you may be better off using a binary or json file instead of csv, since csv is not well suited for storing structured variables like yours.

`pickle` is a lot simpler, but creates a binary file:

```
import pickle

# store some sample data
list1 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
         [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
         [(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]

with open('file1.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(list1, f)

# read the data back
with open('file1.p', 'rb') as f:
    list2 = pickle.load(f)

list1 == list2
# True
```

`json` creates a more readable file, but the code is messier.

```
import json

# store some sample data
list1 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
         [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)],
         [(2, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]

with open('file1.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list1, f)

# read the data back
with open('file1.json', 'r') as f:
    list2 = json.load(f)
    # convert inner lists to tuples (json doesn't distinguish them)
    list2 = [[tuple(t) for t in row] for row in list2]

list1 == list2
# True
```